# How to check phone number on dialer through Espresso - Dialer fired through autoLink

Tags: android, android-intent, android-espresso

I'm trying to check whether the phone dialer opens with the correct phone number through Espresso but not really able to do it so far. 
I've tried:

```
    Intents.init();

    Intent stubIntent = new Intent();
    Instrumentation.ActivityResult stubResult = new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, stubIntent);
    intending(hasAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)).respondWith(stubResult);
    intended(Matchers.allOf(hasAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL), hasData(Uri.parse("+3531234567"))));
```

And also

```
    Intents.init();

    intended(allOf(hasAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL), hasData(Uri.parse("+3531234567"))));
```

The dialer is being triggered through an autoLink on the TextView on my XML if that helps in any way?

```
android:autoLink="all"
```

and that's the dialer opened by Espresso

[image]

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really doesn't seem to work with the autoLink and based on @Aaron's great help that's what worked for me.

1 - ***Remove autoLink*** from TextView

2 - ***Trigger the intent*** normally through an OnClickListener as

```
tvCallNumber.setText(phone); // phone = +3531234567

    tvCallNumber.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone)); 
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

3 - Make sure the phone number is ***prefixed with "tel:"***

4 - Have the ***right order*** for the test actions

```
    Intents.init();

    Intent stubIntent = new Intent();
    Instrumentation.ActivityResult stubResult = new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, stubIntent);

    intending(hasAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)).respondWith(stubResult);
    onView(withId(R.id.tv_call_number)).perform(click());
    intended(Matchers.allOf(hasAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL), hasData(Uri.parse("tel:+3531234567"))));
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to prefix your number with `tel:`, so try:

```
Uri.parse("tel:+3531234567")
```

Comment: Hi @Aaron, thanks so much for your reply. That makes sense and I added it now and tried using it both methods but still haven't got a successful result I'm afraid. The phone number comes from a network call if that helps? Thanks again.

Comment: Tried again hardcoding "+3531234567" to my textview but still got no successful pass.

Comment: Do you have an error log? Just want to see what was it expecting.

Comment: Sure, that's it here: ```junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 0 intents.

IntentMatcher: (has action: is "android.intent.action.DIAL" and has data: is <tel:+3531234567>)

Matched intents:[]``` Thank you.

Comment: I'm trying to find some piece of code that helps me to get exactly what this intent has instead but couldn't find it yet

Comment: Oh there was no intents fired.. did you forget to perform click in your test before you call intended?

Comment: No, I have this before Intents.init() `onView(withId(R.id.tv_call_number)).perform(click());`

Comment: Your test should look like: intending -> click to dial -> intended

Comment: Ah you should call init first.. then intending.. then click.. then assert with intended.

Comment: Changed it now to `Intents.init();

        Intent stubIntent = new Intent();
        Instrumentation.ActivityResult stubResult = new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, stubIntent);
        onView(withId(R.id.tv_call_number)).perform(click());

        intending(hasAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)).respondWith(stubResult);
        intended(Matchers.allOf(hasAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL), hasData(Uri.parse("tel:+3531234567"))));` but still no success. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, but no.. swap intending and click.. please check the order in my last comment

Comment: I'm with you Aaron. Tried with `Intents.init();

        Intent stubIntent = new Intent();
        Instrumentation.ActivityResult stubResult = new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, stubIntent);

        intending(hasAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)).respondWith(stubResult);
        onView(withId(R.id.tv_call_number)).perform(click());
        intended(Matchers.allOf(hasAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL), hasData(Uri.parse("tel:+3531234567"))));` but again nope

Comment: The same as before.

Comment: Updated the code with the image of my dialer. Thanks so much again.

Comment: Yes, I tried removing the auto link and just firing a normal intent and the dialer opens but still nothing happens.

Comment: tvCallNumber.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:3531234567"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

Comment: Oh you didn't have a + sign in the code, could you please remove + sign from the test too?

Comment: Got something here. I think it's nearly working. Will be back to you shortly. :)

Comment: It worked now! Just updated the steps for it. It really doesn't seem to work with autoLink but it worked triggering the normal intent action. I think you should get officially promoted as my Espresso buddy now as is the third time you help me with an issue. Thanks so so much for that!!! :)